# PHP - PRINTF Not Printing array $variable[$i]

Tags: php

I'm trying to `printf` a variable with some 000 on the left side but only print the 000 and no print the variable.

```
$activePlayers1 = array(3)
numero = $activePlayers1[$i];        
printf('000',$numero);
```

The result of this is 000 and no print the 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to pad with zeros, you should use a *padding specifier*:

```
<?php

$numero = 5;
printf("%'.09d", $numero);

?>
```

yields

```
000000005
```

[Try it yourself](https://repl.it/repls/DramaticFlippantDrawings)

The `d` is a *type specifier*, used to treat the variable value as an integer and display it as a decimal, and you can find the full list of type specifiers under the [sprintf documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

> d - the argument is treated as an integer and presented as a (signed)
>   decimal number.

Comment: Just `%09d` is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
 $activePlayers1 = array(3)
     numero = $activePlayers1[$i];        
     printf('%d',$numero);
```